# Python socket servers don't see abrupt disconnect when using docker network

Tags: python, docker, sockets, docker-compose

When running a socket server and client in python, an abrupt disconnect by the client is handled differently by the server when running both locally versus running both in docker containers and through a docker network. If it matters, all of these tests are done on a Linux machine.

Here is a simple socket server that serves incrementing bytes:

```py
import socket
import time

def main():
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 12345))
    server_socket.listen(1)

    print('Server bound and listening.')

    try:
        # Wait for a connection
        print('Waiting for a connection...')
        connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        
        print('Connection established from:', client_address)
        
        try:
            # Serve incrementing bytes
            current_byte = 0
            while True:
                connection.sendall(bytes([current_byte]))
                
                print(f'Sent byte: {current_byte}')

                current_byte = (current_byte + 1) % 256
                time.sleep(1)
            
        finally:
            connection.close()
            print('Connection closed.')
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Server interrupted by user, shutting down.')

    finally:
        # Clean up the server socket
        server_socket.close()
        print('Server socket closed.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is the corresponding client to consume the incrementing bytes:

```py
import socket
import time
import os

# Override when running in docker to point to the correct host.
SERVER_HOST = os.getenv("SERVER_HOST", "localhost")


def main():
    # Wait for server to come up.
    time.sleep(1)

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((SERVER_HOST, 12345))

    while True:
        bytes_received = sock.recv(1)
        print(f"Received bytes: {str(bytes_received)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run these scripts locally (no docker containers and loopback), a `BrokenPipeError` is raised by `connection.sendall(...)` when I either Ctrl+C or kill the client.

Server:

```
Server bound and listening.
Waiting for a connection...
Connection established from: ('127.0.0.1', 44778)
Sent byte: 0
Sent byte: 1
Sent byte: 2
Sent byte: 3
Connection closed.
Server socket closed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/socket_server.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "/path/to/socket_server.py", line 23, in main
    connection.sendall(bytes([current_byte]))
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Client (interrupted with a user-input Ctrl+C):

```
Received bytes: b'\x00'
Received bytes: b'\x01'
Received bytes: b'\x02'
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/socket_client.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/path/to/socket_client.py", line 17, in main
    bytes_received = sock.recv(1)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt
```

However, when running in docker containers and over a docker network, the server never detects that the client disconnected. Here is a docker-compose file to spin up the services and connect them together:

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  socket-net:
    name: socket-net
    external: false

services:
  client:
    image: python:3.11
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    environment:
      # Show prints without explicit flush
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
      SERVER_HOST: "server"
    command: ["python", "/scripts/socket_client.py"]
    networks:
      - socket-net
  
  server:
    hostname: server
    image: python:3.11
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    environment:
      # Show prints without explicit flush
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    command: ["python", "/scripts/socket_server.py"]
    networks:
      - socket-net
```

When I interrupt the `socket_client` with a `docker kill`, the server doesn't always raise an exception:

```
ebenevedes@machine:/path/to/socket_mre$ docker compose up --force-recreate
[+] Running 3/0
 ✔ Network socket-net             Created                                          0.0s 
 ✔ Container socket_mre-client-1  Created                                          0.0s 
 ✔ Container socket_mre-server-1  Created                                          0.0s 
Attaching to client-1, server-1
server-1  | Server bound and listening.
server-1  | Waiting for a connection...
server-1  | Connection established from: ('172.25.18.2', 54428)
server-1  | Sent byte: 0
client-1  | Received bytes: b'\x00'
client-1  | Received bytes: b'\x01'
server-1  | Sent byte: 1
client-1  | Received bytes: b'\x02'
server-1  | Sent byte: 2
client-1  | Received bytes: b'\x03'
server-1  | Sent byte: 3
client-1 exited with code 137 # Killed with `docker kill socket_mre-client-1` from a different terminal.
server-1  | Sent byte: 4
server-1  | Sent byte: 5
server-1  | Sent byte: 6
server-1  | Sent byte: 7
server-1  | Sent byte: 8
... # Server continues to send bytes without raising an Exception
```

1. Why do sockets exhibit different behavior when connecting through loopback versus through a docker network?
2. How can I consistently detect a disconnecting client from the server, no matter what the network path is between the server and client? I have seen a similar issue with EKS K8s deployments, but don't have a minimum reproducible example for that case.

Comment: TCP simply does not have that kind of control: it will just wait for another packet. You will need to set a timeout yourself - and, if needed, implement a "keep alive" message on  your ad-hoc protocol. This is one of the reasons people will resort to higher level protocols than TCP/IP (like HTTP, MQTT, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

My first answer doesn't really solve the issue. A more useful answer is to have the server listen for a response.

client:

```
import socket
import time
import os
import signal

# Override when running in docker to point to the correct host.
SERVER_HOST = os.getenv("SERVER_HOST", "localhost")

def main():
    # Wait for server to come up.
    time.sleep(1)

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((SERVER_HOST, 12345))

    while True:
        bytes_received = sock.recv(1)
        print(f"Received bytes: {str(bytes_received)}")
        sock.send(b"ok")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

server:

```
import socket
import time

def main():
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 12345))
    server_socket.listen(1)

    print('Server bound and listening.')

    try:
        # Wait for a connection
        print('Waiting for a connection...')
        connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        
        print('Connection established from:', client_address)
        
        try:
            # Serve incrementing bytes
            current_byte = 0
            while True:
                connection.sendall(bytes([current_byte]))
                
                print(f'Sent byte: {current_byte}')

                current_byte = (current_byte + 1) % 256
                confirm = connection.recv(2)

                if confirm == b"":
                    connection.close()
                    break
                time.sleep(1)
            
        finally:
            connection.close()
            print('Connection closed.')
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Server interrupted by user, shutting down.')

    finally:
        # Clean up the server socket
        server_socket.close()
        print('Server socket closed.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your client:

```
import socket
import time
import os
import signal

# Override when running in docker to point to the correct host.
SERVER_HOST = os.getenv("SERVER_HOST", "localhost")

def main():
    # Wait for server to come up.
    time.sleep(1)

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((SERVER_HOST, 12345))

    def exit_handler(signum, frame):        
        sock.close()
        time.sleep(1)
        raise(SystemExit)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_handler)

    while True:
        bytes_received = sock.recv(1)
        print(f"Received bytes: {str(bytes_received)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only catches SIGINT and SIGTERM, not SIGKILL.